# Save a DOM to a variable in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to save a DOM to a variable (let) and render it later. But it throws me out an unexpected token and marks my variablename and I'm a little confused why :D.. maybe just a small mistake.. whatever.. here's the code "let whichCustomer" is the variable in question - obviously.

```
class RegisterForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  whatCustomer: 'searching'
};

// Welche Art von Kunde
this.handleKind = this.handleKind.bind(this);
}

// State setzen von "Art von Kunde"
handleKind(event) {
   this.setState({whatCustomer: event.target.value});

}

let whichCustomer = (<button className="valueButton" name="whatCustomer" value="searching"  onClick={this.handleKind}>Suchender</button>
<button className="valueButton" name="whatCustomer" value="sponsor" onClick={this.handleKind}>Sponsor</button>
<button className="valueButton" name="whatCustomer" value="adverter" onClick={this.handleKind}>Werbeflächenbetreiber</button>
);

render() {
  return (
    <div className="registerForm" id="sponsor">
      <h1 className="turquoise" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        Jetzt direkt registrieren und loslegen!
      </h1>
      <br />
      <br />
      <form>
        Was sind Sie?
        <br />
        {whichCustomer}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

I'm a little new to react.. have mercy on me please :D

Comment: Add the code of your whole component so we can see if this is a dumb component, function or class style component. Regularly, you could call your variable as {this.whichCustomer}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code, I am assuming that you've written `let whichCustomer` inside the class component (which is why you're getting unexpected token). Inside class component you cannot declare a variable. You have to write the `whichCustomer` without the `let` keyword.

> Properties specified in a class definition are assigned the same attributes as if they appeared in an object literal.

```
whichCustomer = (<button className="valueButton" name="whatCustomer" value="searching"  onClick={this.handleKind}>Suchender</button>
<button className="valueButton" name="whatCustomer" value="sponsor" onClick={this.handleKind}>Sponsor</button>
<button className="valueButton" name="whatCustomer" value="adverter" onClick={this.handleKind}>Werbeflächenbetreiber</button>
);
```

also add the `this` keyword to access the property.

```js
whichCustomer = (<button className="valueButton" name="whatCustomer" value="searching"  onClick={this.handleKind}>Suchender</button>
<button className="valueButton" name="whatCustomer" value="sponsor" onClick={this.handleKind}>Sponsor</button>
<button className="valueButton" name="whatCustomer" value="adverter" onClick={this.handleKind}>Werbeflächenbetreiber</button>
);

render() {
  return (
    <div className="registerForm" id="sponsor">
      <h1 className="turquoise" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        Jetzt direkt registrieren und loslegen!
      </h1>
      <br />
      <br />
      <form>
        Was sind Sie?
        <br />
        {this.whichCustomer}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you :D

But still wondering.. why no declaration inside the class component?

Answer (score -1):

Its better to make `stateless component`.

**WhichCustomer**

```
const WhichCustomer = ({handleKind}) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <button
      className="valueButton"
      name="whatCustomer"
      value="searching"
      onClick={handleKind}>Suchender</button>
    <button
      className="valueButton"
      name="whatCustomer"
      value="sponsor"
      onClick={handleKind}>
      Sponsor
    </button>
    <button
      className="valueButton"
      name="whatCustomer"
      value="adverter"
      onClick={handleKind}>Werbeflächenbetreiber</button>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

**render:**

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="registerForm" id="sponsor">

      <WhichCustomer handleKind={this.handleKind}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```